# How to sort range by multiple priorities?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a small desire with my football table...

I want to sort automatically range EC35:EL49 by COLUMN EF (OBP) which is FIRST priority and when the participants are on equal points by COLUMN EF (OBP), then sort by column EH (MS) and when participants are still on equal points by COLUMN EH (MS), then sort finally by column EJ (MBP).

Is it possible?

I have a code in apps script but this sorts only by column EF.

Thanks in advance!

Table link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ZyUuDAp85Vr76NMmqQXuLqTUMMuHP6sQu2gvQREhDU/

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula**

```
=SORT(EF35:EL49,1,0,3,0,5,0)
```

[image]

**Note**
Unhide the columns to see the full input and output on your sheet.

Comment: @Dimaz You cannot hide the output rows if you have to change them, but you can hide the input rows.